# Matching srcset with media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I'd like to match the "w" (i assume width, but it is definitely not in pixels) value in an srcset:

```
srcset="img/coverm.jpg 1600w, img/cover.jpg 2000w"

@media screen and (max-width:1600px) { #cover {height:103vw;} }
```

to a media query's device width. This above obviously does not work as 1600w and 1600px are different values. I've never heard of a media query before that targets the same value as what is in the srcset as "w". Since using the same number results in nothing expected (eg. applying style to an image if it uses the mobile image) I'm a little bit stuck with this one.

How do I match the media query to the 1600w?

Comment: I've also seen (min-device-width: 768px) used somewhere, but that is also in pixels not in the "w" unit

Comment: we have sizes attribute to apply based on screen width take a look at https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/#sizes-in-css . after applying screen sizes in sizes attr -> write media query for that screen size.

Comment: "sizes" is actually the same as what is written in my example in the srcset attribute - the problem I have is how do I match that "w" value to a media query - since there is no "w" value to be used in media queries. Lets take 1600w as an example, I cant wrap my head around that what pixel width at what device dpi that matches to? since its two numbers you cant really rely on that to match to one number  since dpi can change with different devices where as "w" I assume is a fixed unit which is all the same for any device?